# how to compare to chars using pointers in c?

Tags: c

I have an assignment to complete in C.

> Write a function that recives two pointers to strings, checks if they have the same letter and if does, it will return a pointer to the letter found in the first string.

How can I write this function?

I wrote this and it's not working:

```
char *checkSameChr(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    while (*str1)
    {
        while (*str2)
        {
            if (*str2==*str1)
                return str1;
            *str2++;
        }
        *str1++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What does *"is not working"* mean? Does not compile? Crashes? Produces wrong results? What input did you test it with? What output did you get and what output did you expect? How far did you get with *debugging* your problem?

Comment: Tell us now it is not working. What inputs are you giving, what do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening? As-is, it looks like your code won't even compile due to using an undeclared variable `c`.

Comment: it gives me the wrong result, i tried it with "eytan" and "sivan" it should return "an" but returns NULL

Comment: And how did you debug it?

Comment: sorry, it was writen wrong, now it's written as i wrote it. the "c" there replaced with "*str1"

Comment: @user3661842: Do yourself a favour and learn how to use a *debugger*. Single-step through your function, inspect the variables, etc .... (Hint: What does `str2` point to when `str1` is incremented?)

Comment: You are not reseting `str2` after each traversal (the inner loop), so it goes beyond the string data for the 2nd and subsequent characters of `str1` and accesses unallocated memory.

Comment: This question should be closed, @user, just see http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to show that you have researched the problem yourself.

Comment: quote : `the same letter`, singular. Aren't you supposed to check just one character? Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the original `str2`. Otherwise, after the first character of `str1` is checked for, `str2` points to the end of the string.

```
char *checkSameChr(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    char* s2 = str2;
    while (*str1)
    {
        while (*s2)
        {
            if (*s2==*str1)
                return str1;
            s2++;
        }
        str1++;
        s2 = str2;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The dereferencing operator in `*s2++` and `*str1++` is not really needed.